# JQuery load json data on page load then call the the json data every 60 seconds

Tags: jquery

I have a script that calls some json data from another scripts but there is a delay when the page loads. I have tried positioning the "setInterval(function)" but I can't get the data to load when the script first runs.

Have I got the setInterval setup correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
setInterval(function(){
$.getJSON("get_data.php", function(json){
json = json[0].data;
var tr ;
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientname-text'>" + json[i].ClientName + "</div></td>");
    tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='roomname-text'>" + json[i].RoomName + "</div></td>");
    tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='time-text'>" + json[i].RoomFromTime + " - " + json[i].RoomToTime + "</div></td>");

 $('table').append(tr);
}
});
}, 60000);
});
```

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You can check your `get_data.php` file return correct json data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to make the function in your `setInterval` a named function, call it, then use the `setInterval` to keep calling it, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function get_data() {
      $.getJSON("get_data.php", function(json){
      json = json[0].data;
      var tr ;
      for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
          tr = $('<tr/>');
          tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientname-text'>" + json[i].ClientName + "</div></td>");
          tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='roomname-text'>" + json[i].RoomName + "</div></td>");
          tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='time-text'>" + json[i].RoomFromTime + " - " + json[i].RoomToTime + "</div></td>");

       $('table').append(tr);
      }
      });

    }

    get_data();
    setInterval(get_data,60000)
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Put all of this in a function:

```
    $.getJSON("get_data.php", function(json){
json = json[0].data;
var tr ;
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientname-text'>" + json[i].ClientName + "</div></td>");
    tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='roomname-text'>" + json[i].RoomName + "</div></td>");
    tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='time-text'>" + json[i].RoomFromTime + " - " + json[i].RoomToTime + "</div></td>");

 $('table').append(tr);
}
```

Then call that function, then call `setInterval` again with that function. That way the function will execute immediately and you'll get your data load without delay.

Comment: hi, which function?

Comment: Name the function whatever you want. That's up to you.

Comment: @CumminUp07 do you have any idea how I can change my script from using 'append' to 'html()'. At the moment the data is not getting updated when the getJSON call is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

Her you go with one more solution

```js
setInterval(function(){
   $.getJSON("get_data.php", function(json){
   json = json[0].data;
   var tr ;
   for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
      tr = $('<tr/>');
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientname-text'>" + json[i].ClientName + "</div></td>");
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='roomname-text'>" + json[i].RoomName + "</div></td>");
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='time-text'>" + json[i].RoomFromTime + " - " + json[i].RoomToTime + "</div></td>");

      $('table').append(tr);
    }
  });

  return arguments.callee;
}(), 60000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It's a **self invoking function** inside **setInterval**.

jsfiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/4gkzqhgq/1/